# python-xarray: rolling mean example

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

I have a file which is monthly data for one year (12 points). The data starts in December and ends in November. I'm hoping to create a 3-month running mean file which would be DJF, JFM, ..., SON (10 points)

I noticed there is a [`DataArray.rolling`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.rolling.html#xarray.DataArray.rolling) function which returns a rolling window option and I think would be useful for this. However, I haven't found any examples using the rolling function. I admit i'm not familiar with [bottleneck](https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck), [`pandas.rolling_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) or the more recent [`pandas.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) so my entry level is fairly low.

Here's some code to test:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, num=181); lon = np.linspace(0, 359, num=360)
# Define monthly average time as day in middle of month
time = pd.date_range('15/12/1999', periods=12, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))
# Create data as 0:11 at each grid point
a = np.linspace(0,11,num=12)
# expand to 2D
a2d = np.repeat(tmp[:, np.newaxis], len(lat), axis=1)
# expand to 3D
a3d = np.repeat(a2d[:, :, np.newaxis], len(lon), axis=2)
# I'm sure there was a cleaner way to do that...

da = xr.DataArray(a3d, coords=[time, lat, lon], dims=['time','lat','lon'])  

# Having a stab at the 3-month rolling mean
da.rolling(dim='time',window=3).mean()
# Error output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-132-9d64cc09c263>", line 1, in <module>
da.rolling(dim='time',window=3).mean()
File "/Users/Ray/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py", line 478, in rolling
center=center, **windows)
File "/Users/Ray/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/rolling.py", line 126, in __init__
center=center, **windows)
File "/Users/Ray/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/rolling.py", line 62, in __init__
raise ValueError('exactly one dim/window should be provided')
```

ValueError: exactly one dim/window should be provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. The [rolling method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.rolling.html#xarray.DataArray.rolling) takes a key/value pair that maps as `dim`/`window_size`. This should work for you.

```
da.rolling(time=3).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks. The easiest way I thought of dropping the nans was simply
da.rolling(time=winlen).mean()[winlen-1::,:,:]
not sure if there was something better.

Mind if I make a little PR to add this example to the DOC of https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/master/xarray/core/rolling.py

Is there a list of the functions available to the rolling object e.g. mean, sum, median etc.?

Comment: So there are two things you can do that would help with the nans: 1) you can set `min_periods` to an integer (e.g. `da.rolling(min_periods=0, time=3).mean()`), or 2) you can drop the NaNs using `dropna` (e.g. da.rolling(time=3).mean().dropna('time)`). We're always open to folks help improve the xarray documentation.